# Inheritance policy when designing the base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class and a derived class both in design phase. The base class will remain one but many derived class will inherit from it. So it's very costly to make change to derived classes in the future and I'm looking for the best design to prevent this.

In fact derived class only needs a few methods to override (if needed) but it's tempting to reveal more details to it.

My question is about the policy which is extensible in future.

Can I minimize the inherited methods/properties to derived class and reveal more in the next versions if needed without any change to derived classes ?

Or I should reveal anything that maybe used by derived classes in the future and let them to choose if they need them or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can without problem change more methods and properties from private to protected at a later point. Only rule is that existing protected members can never be made private again

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely minimize the number of protected methods for now. It's always hard to predict the future, too many things change during development/design of a class, so the best thing is to keep it [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and make the best design for what you know **now** not what might or might be needed at some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others have posted, you'll want to consider who is the target audience for your base class. Are they part of an API or framework that is intended to be extended by your customers or other external consumers, or is this abstraction fully under your own control (ie. only you will be implementing derivations)?

Depending on the answer, you may need to think very carefully about the base classes you expose -- it can be difficult to design a good, flexible inheritance scheme.

Comment: No API, it's fully under my control. Derived classes also implement an interface which is also implemented by base class of course.